# Troubleshooting PyQt4 Matplotlib

Tags: python, multithreading, pandas, matplotlib, pyqt4

So I managed to write a PyQt4 Widget, which can run a loop in a thread. 2 Things are done in the thread.

1. A loop is started and a signal is emitted to a progress bar to give info about progress. (I know this could be done better but for my task is sufficient)
2. After the loop is done running, a pandas.DataFrame is emitted from inside the thread to matplotlib, which is outside the thread and in the main Widget class.

Everything works fine, you can move the Widget while the loop is processed. The only Problem is that when the Widget is moved at the same time as the plot is popped up (or the processing is done), everything freezes. Not only the Widget and the plot but also my windows desktop. I can get out of it with task manager. Any Advice how to circumvent this?

I am using Python 3.6 (32 bit)

code:

```
import sys
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

class App(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super(App, self).__init__()
        self.setGeometry(500, 300, 820, 350)
        self.setWindowTitle("Program")
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):

        #Buttons
        btnposx = 30
        btnposy = 50

        self.btn4 = QPushButton('Load', self)
        self.btn4.move(btnposx,btnposy+220)       
        self.btn4.released.connect(self.thread)

        #ProgressBar
        self.pb = QProgressBar(self)
        self.pb.move(btnposx+150,btnposy+220)
        self.pb.resize(470,27)        

        self.show()

    @pyqtSlot(float)
    def load(self, val):
        self.pb.setValue(val)

    @pyqtSlot(object)
    def plot(self, pq):
        pq.plot(grid = 1)
        plt.show()

    def thread(self):
        self.thread_ = Thread()
        self.thread_.pb_signal.connect(self.load, Qt.QueuedConnection)
        self.thread_.plot_signal.connect(self.plot, Qt.QueuedConnection)
        self.thread_.start()

class Thread(QThread):
    pb_signal = pyqtSignal(float)
    plot_signal = pyqtSignal(object)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        QThread.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

    def __del__(self):
        self.wait()

    @pyqtSlot()    
    def run(self):       
        val = 0
        self.pb_signal.emit(20)
        l = range(50000000)
        for i in l:
            val += 1
        self.pb_signal.emit(60)
        self.pb_signal.emit(100)
        pq = pd.DataFrame(data = {'col1':[1,2,3,4,5,6], 'col2':[6,5,4,3,2,1]})
        self.plot_signal.emit(pq)        
        return

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = App()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: You do not have to perform the plot using matplotlib since the eventloop of PyQt and matplotlib will be blocked. What you must do is as indicated in the links you use FigureCanvas and then add the pandas.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But isn't canvas for plots inside the widget? How do I make a popup plot, like matplotlib does?

Comment: FigureCanvas is a widget.